# Proving $f^{-1}(f(x))=x \forall x\in X.$ (if f is bijective).

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

> Suppose there is a function that is bijective $f: X \to Y$, and it has
>   an inverse $f^{-1}:Y\to X$. Verify that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x, \forall x\in
> > X$.

**Here is my attempt:**

If $f^{-1}(f(x))=x, \forall x\in X$, then by applying $f$ to both sides:
$f(f^{-1}(f(x))=f(x)$

By surjectivity: for each $f(x)\in y, \exists f^{-1}(f(x))\in X$ Such that the equation is true.

**For an arbitrary $y=f(x)$, there exists an arbitrary $x=f^{-1}(f(x))$, then if the proposition is false, this equation should hold:**

$f(y)\neq f(x)$

Which is true iff $y\neq x$, but that contradicts the subjectivity statement.

**To conclude**: My proof is a mess and I believe that I have used circular logic, more so where the bolded text is.

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: What is your definition of inverse? I ask this because that what you are trying to verify is true *by definition* (hence does not need any verification).

Comment: It is not very clear what the question is. When you say that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$, it is usually meant that $ff^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_Y$ and $f^{-1}f=\mathrm{id}_X$, i.e., both $f(f^{-1}(y))=y \ \forall y\in Y$ and $f^{-1}(f(x))=x \ \forall x\in X$ hold. What do you assume, and what do you want to verify?
I think that Kavi Rama Murthy understood your question: you assume to have right inverse (the first condition I wrote), and want to prove it is also left inverse (the second condition). Your proof then starts wrong, because you already assume what you want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f^{-1}(f(x))$. Then $f(y)=f(f^{-1}(f(x))=f(x)$ by definition of $f^{-1}$. [$f(f^{-1}u)=u$ for all $u$ in the range of $f$. I am taking $u$ to be $f(x)$]. Since $f$ is one-to-one this implies $y=x$ as required, .

Comment: IMV this needs a further explaining of the definition. What is it, and how is it used? It seems that you look at it as only a right-inverse.